# python pyinstaller dont print in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, printing, console, pyinstaller

So my program is work perfectly when I simple start the python file. But when I used the pyinstaller is not working, not print the output(Date + count.).

```
import win32com.client
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, date
from tqdm import tqdm
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tkinter import *

counts = []
dates = []
def outlookc():
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    explorer = outlook.ActiveExplorer()
    if explorer is not None:
        folder = explorer.CurrentFolder
        utc = pytz.UTC
        date = datetime(int(e1.get()), int(e2.get()), int(e3.get()))
        start_date = utc.localize(date)
        end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=int(e4.get()))
        restriction = f"[ReceivedTime] >= '{start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')}' AND [ReceivedTime] < '{end_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')}'"
        filtered_items = folder.Items.Restrict(restriction)

        emails_by_date = defaultdict(list)
        for item in tqdm(filtered_items, desc="Counting emails"):  
            if item.Class == 43:
                try:
                    received_date = item.ReceivedTime.date()
                    emails_by_date[received_date].append(item)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                print(f" Ezt nem számolja bele: {item.Subject}")
                pass


        for received_date, emails in sorted(emails_by_date.items()):
            count = len(emails)
            dates.append(received_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            counts.append(count)
            print(f"{received_date}: {count}")

    else:
        print("Nem találok aktív mappát.")     
    
master = Tk()
master.geometry("300x300")
master.title(" Outlook e-mail counter ")
master.attributes('-topmost',True)
Label(master, 
         text="Kezdő év():").grid(row=0)
Label(master, 
         text="Kezdő hó").grid(row=1)
Label(master, 
         text="Kezdő nap").grid(row=2)
Label(master, 
         text="Hány napot").grid(row=3)
Label(master, 
         text="*2023").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(master, 
         text="*2").grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(master, 
         text="*8").grid(row=2, column=2)
Label(master, 
         text="*1").grid(row=3, column=2)
e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

Button(master, text='Számol', command=outlookc).grid(row=5, 
                                                       column=1, 
                                                       sticky=W, 
                                                       pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

This picture shows the corresponding output, which I would like to see, in this case I start the python file:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ym78.jpg)
And this picture does not show, for the given date, how much he calculated, this is a exe what i made with pyinstaller:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pwv9.jpg)

why are the two outputs different?

Comment: could you attach the images in the question itself rather than having it as hyperlinks?

Comment: How did you compile the app? what pyinstaller command did you use?

Comment: Hi, i used pyinstaller --onedir app.py, i tried with --onefile doesnt work...

Comment: Update:
I solved.
First: I used pyinstaller --debug all app.py, and i saw this # win32timezone not found in pyz
Second: pyinstaller --hiddenimport win32timezone -F app.py and now its working